# Different compatibility versions in one program's webbrowser controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I have a VB.Net application with multiple WebBrowser Controls embedded in it, and they are both trying to access different sites. One of the sites is completely broken when loaded in IE7 document mode, so I made sure to change the feature browser emulation registry key to the latest installed versions of IE for those who are using it (IE10 or IE11). This worked great and now all of the controls are running in the latest version of IE. Unfortunately, the web page for the other control must be run in IE7/Compatibility mode or else the page has errors. Just a note, the web-page that needs IE7/Compatibility mode doesn't specify this and doesn't automatically make IE use compatibility mode.

This means I have one WebBrowser that only works with IE7 document mode, and one that only works IE8+ document mode within the same application.

Things I have tried/considered:

- Adding the site to compatibility view in IE and then re-launching the application (It seems to ignore this)
- Using all different versions of feature_browser_emulation keys to see if one will allow for it to work
- (Haven't figured out if possible) Somehow have the other browser run in a different process so it can have it's key set separately.
- (Not sure if I was doing this right, but it didn't seem to work) Injecting html into the website that needs IE7/Compatibility mode to tell the browser to use IE=EmulateIE7 using the <meta> tag.

Is there any way to achieve this without a special library? I'd rather not have to deal with bringing in any extra dependencies if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this question in a search, I have a potential solution. We actually have a couple of customers that are doing this same thing (their application is using the .Net Framework Browser Control), and what they have done is to take advantage of a feature within IE11 called Enterprise Mode. From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-overview-for-ie11:

> Enterprise Mode is a compatibility mode that runs on Internet Explorer 11, letting websites render using a modified browser configuration that’s designed to emulate either Windows Internet Explorer 8 or Windows Internet Explorer 7, avoiding the common compatibility problems associated with web apps written and tested on older versions of Internet Explorer.

There is a reference at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-schema-version-1-guidance which explains how to create the XML which is needed to define this list

Microsoft has also released a tool ([Enterprise Mode Site List Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/use-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-manager)) to make it easier to manage this list - but then the tool would need to be installed on any computer running your application.  **BUT**, you can use the tool to define your list, then export that and include with your application..

Besides IE7/IE8 Enterprise Mode, you can also set Document Mode to IE5 through IE11.